# laravel route exist but 404 error returned

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm using laravel 6.20 and i've just start my laravel project in local and i have a problem that my route exist but 404 error returned i tried to clear&cache route but nothing works for this problem
route : /market/variety
in route:list

```
|        | GET|HEAD | market/variety                        | market.variety.form       | App\Http\Controllers\Market\ProductController@vareityForm                 | web,auth |
```

in web :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Market', 'prefix' => 'market'], function () {

Route::get('variety/', 'ProductController@vareityForm')->name('market.variety.form');
```

i tried this commands

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan dump-autoload
```

i checked route conflict and there is no problem in routes that i can find
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: your queston is not fully clear for me

Comment: i cant access this route this is the main problem

Comment: How are you accessing this route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace this

```
Route::get('variety/', 'ProductController@vareityForm')->name('market.variety.form');
```

Into

```
Route::get('/variety', 'ProductController@vareityForm')->name('market.variety.form');
```

Then run command  `php artisan optimize`

I hope you got your solution .

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Market', 'prefix' => 'market'], function () {
    
    Route::get('/variety', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'vareityForm'])->name('market.variety.form');
});
```

after run command:

```
php artisan optimize

php artisan view:cache

php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

if your method not have any response func , ex return, echo or you don't have any data return. so laravel don't understand what u do

Answer (score -2):

try to use another controller and if the proplem solved so the proplem in the controller